# Unable to fetch data in view using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

This is my first project on laravel.I want to fetch some data in my website home page but i am unable to do this.getting some error.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Validator;
use App;
use Lang;
use DB;
//for password encryption or hash protected
use Hash;
use App\Administrator;

//for authenitcate login data
use Auth;



use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

class WebController extends Controller
{
function loadPage(){
    $categories = DB::table('categories')
        ->leftJoin('categories_description','categories_description.categories_id', '=', 'categories.categories_id')
        ->select('categories.categories_id as id', 'categories.categories_image as image',  'categories.categories_icon as icon',  'categories.date_added as date_added', 'categories.last_modified as last_modified', 'categories_description.categories_name as name', 'categories_description.language_id')
        ->where('parent_id', '0')->where('categories_description.language_id', '1');

    return view("home")->with('categories', $categories);
}
}
```

this is my controller.getting this error.

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::$name (View: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/rssl/resources/views/home.blade.php)

Comment: Are your connection parameters set up correctly in your .env file?

Comment: yes...My admin panel already running as a admin folder inside controller

Comment: missing ->get() in your query ?

Comment: thank you so much....I am very new in laravel

Comment: @Ahmed, Can you Add the comment as an answer
Arpan Remember to add a Accepted Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing a get() at the in of your query

```
$categories = DB::table('categories')
        ->leftJoin('categories_description','categories_description.categories_id', '=', 'categories.categories_id')
        ->select('categories.categories_id as id', 'categories.categories_image as image',  'categories.categories_icon as icon',  'categories.date_added as date_added', 'categories.last_modified as last_modified', 'categories_description.categories_name as name', 'categories_description.language_id')
        ->where('parent_id', '0')->where('categories_description.language_id', '1')->get();
```